# Data type changing after multiplying two columns in MS Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I want to multiply two columns with each other and use the following code

```
CDbl(amount) * CDbl(weighting)
AS [amount_weighted],
```

"Amount" is a regular number while "weighting" is a value between 0 and 1. 
The resulting column is formatted as "short text" in Access, although it should be a number. Occasionally the column "weighting" or "amount" can be empty, may this be a reason for the malfunctioning? 
The wrong formatting gives causes a "number stores as text" error when I want to export the resulting column into Excel.

Comment: try nz(amount,0) * nz(weighting,0) as [amount_weighted]

Comment: Number stored as text isn't actually an error - you can convert them to a number by clicking on the warning flag

Comment: @krishKM: Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that single lines were empty caused the Problem.

```
nz(amount,0) * nz(weighting,0) as [amount_weighted]
```

Using this instead of CDbl and therefore inserting "0" into the empty lines solved the problem.